# how do i dynamically display gallery view on django

Tags: python, django

i want to display a gallery view dynamically by adding images directly from the admin panel.
This is the code,i have added site.register in admin.py

gallery.html

```
{% extends 'app/main.html' %}
{% load static %}
{% block content %}

<div class="row container">
{% for imgs in gallery %}
<div class="col-md-4">
    <img class="thumbnail " src="{{gallery.imageURL}}" alt="">
</div>
{% endfor %}
```

```
{% endblock content %}
```

models.py

```
from django.db import models


class Gallery(models.Model):
image=models.ImageField(null=True,blank=True)

@property
def imageURL(self):

    try:
        url=self.image.url
    except:
        url= ''
    return url
```

views.py

```
def gallery(request):
imgs=Gallery.objects.all()
context={'gallery':gallery}
return render(request,"app/gallery.html",context)
```

urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path,include
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.conf import settings


urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('',include('app.urls')),
]
if settings.DEBUG: # new
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Comment: What is your question specifically, you want to make a gallery of images, but what is happening specifically. You should not simply want to do something, you should also try to do it and try everything you can, when you have a specific problem because you publish it here and we all help you.

Comment: you render a template with wrong context and use wrong variable in the for-loop in the code of your template... everything is getting confused

Comment: i have made the changes to the code, im kinds new to django

Comment: @AmanBaid seems you're playing guessing game. Try to debug your app, run it step-by-step, carefully reading everything interpreter prints out. May be pass through a little of tutorials on django. And, after all, ask what REALLY causes difficulties.